# How to linearize the square of a positive continuous variable

Tags: optimization, quadratics, linearization

Suppose we have a positive continuous variables $0 \le x \le UB$ where $UB$ is a known upper bound.

How can we linearize the term $x^2$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in which context you're working. To linearize the function $f(x) = x^2$ at $a \in [0, UB]$ (see [here](http://www.fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4XjIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoiMi41XjIrKDIqMi41KSh4LTIuNSkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNGRjAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyIwIiwiNSIsIjAiLCIyNSJdfV0-)), use:

$f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) \le f(x), \forall x \in [0, UB]$

Since $f$ is convex, the linearization is a lower bound.

Comment: I am working in the context of optimization.I am solving a quadratic problem and i need to add some constraints containing the quadratic term $x^2$ via lazy constraints however lazy constraints must be linear (CPLEX).